# Django-haystack result filtering using attributes?

Tags: django, solr, full-text-search, django-haystack

Can someone show me an example of how to filter fulltext search results with django-haystack using attributes? I went through the tutorial on their website but am still mot sure on how to use haystack.

For instance, let's say I have a
class Product:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

If I want to provide fulltext search on title & description, and
filtering (based on drop-down lists, not free text) on category and
color - what do I need to do? Can I use the forms and views that come with haystack?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at the **faceting** [tutorial/documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest//faceting.html) on the django-haystack website? It walks you through an example of filtering based on author of the `Note` model introduced in the getting started tutorial.

Another option separate from haystack and searching is `django-filter` by Alex Gaynor, it allows you to filter fields based on the contents of the model and not on an index. Therefore it can be used on models that aren't indexed with `django-haystack`. You can check out the repository [here](http://github.com/alex/django-filter). There are good docs in the doc folder and the included tests show off all the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

if we summarize how to add haystack faceting

1. you need to add faceted fields to your index model

```
 title =  CharField(model_attr='title', faceted=True)
 description =  CharField(model_attr='description', faceted=True)
```

1. change your queryset to

```
  sqs = SearchQuerySet().facet('title').facet('description')
```

1. use faceted versions of search form and view that haystack provides in urls.py use this

```
  url(r'^$', FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, searchqueryset=sqs), name='haystack_search'),
```

1. add faceting part to your template like this http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/faceting.html#display-the-facets-in-the-template
2. rebuild your index to see effects of faceting

```
 
   python manage.py rebuild_index
```